# whitespace between <ul> and first <li> gobbled up despite inline-block mode

Tags: html, css

The following JsFiddle is adapted from a [post](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33) I read explaining some on whitespace behavior in HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/ng5yuqjf/4/

According to the piece mentioned above, whitespace in the HTML document is reflected between `inline-block` elements.

However, in the fiddle above, there is no space between the `a` character and the first `<li>`, despite the presence of whitespace between the two elements in the HTML file, and despite everything being set to `inline-block`.

Somehow, it seems like the whitespace between `<ul>` and the first `<li>` doesn't count.

I'm wondering if this is reflected in some spec somewhere, or if it affords a short theoretical explanation.

Thanks!

PS: For reference, the full HTML + css of above fiddle:

```
<tspan>
a</tspan><ul class="people-list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

//

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.people-list {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.people-list li {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #f06;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: `li` and `a` aren't on the same level .. the logic apply between `a` and `ul` and not between a parent element and its child (`ul` and `li)`

Comment: Don't expect whitespace to separate your content. An html-minifier would mess with these expectations. Instead, use margin-left or margin-right for styling.

Comment: @kumar_harsh the OP is aware about white-spaces and he's looking for an explanation of a particular behavior

Comment: _"there is no space between the a character and the first <li>, despite the presence of whitespace between the two elements in the HTML file"_ I see no space between `<tspan>
a</tspan>` and `<ul class="people-list">`

Comment: @j08691 he's talking about the whitespace between `ul` and the first `li`

Comment: @TemaniAfif But that doesn't matter. Nothing can exist between those two elements.

Comment: @j08691 I know, this is what he need to understand and this is the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitespace between `<ul>` and the first `<li>` is in the DOM, so if you want it to show up, just make the ul `display:inline` instead of `display:inline-block`.

Like this:

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.people-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline; /* Add this line */
}
.people-list li {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background: #f06;
    border: 1px solid;
}
style, script, title {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<tspan>
a</tspan><ul class="people-list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

The theoretically reason behind this is that `display:inline-block` creates its own set of line boxes for its contents, which for the ul element includes the white space before the first li element. Because that space is now at the start of a line, is is discarded for rendering according to the rules of `white-space:normal` - [16.6.1 The 'white-space' processing model, "as each line is laid out", step 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#white-space-model).

Whereas, when the ul is `display:inline`, it does not create its own line boxes, the space is then not at the start of a line, and is not discarded when rendering.

Comment: too bad my answer got accepted :/ ... I never thought about the `inline` thing which make my explanation a bit wrong,

Comment: Sorry I screwed up. I think this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: @Labrador Yes you can still change ;) simply click again on the green tick

Comment: Ah... Thanks! :)